# Why does enabling `sourceMap.vendor` decrease source map size?

Tags: angular, source-maps

The Angular has an option `sourceMap.vendor` which

> Resolve vendor packages source maps.

Therefore I expect: when it is `true`, the source map file has a larger size than when the option being `false`.

However, after running the `ng build` with different `sourceMap.vendor` values I see the opposite situation for the file size. E.g. for the project created via `ng init` I get the js.map file size 2.2MB when the `sourceMap.vendor`=`false` and 1.7MB when the `sourceMap.vendor`=`true`

Why does it happen?

Angular version: 15